# Where is the data of the files end with .iq of Calcite?

Tags: apache-calcite

Calcite-core-test-sql-xx.iq files show us the query sentences and the results, so where is the data from?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rp4of.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

A Quidem (`.iq`) script generally starts with a `!use` command like this:

```
!use scott
```

The connection name, in this "scott", becomes an argument to a call to `Quidem.ConnectionFactory.connect(name, reference)`.

That connection is the source for the tables used in subsequent queries in that script. In Calcite, the code that maps "scott" to a particular connection is in [CoreQuidemTest.java](https://github.com/apache/calcite/blob/b0b27e8872b33c5ab203e0e2365d267a594c80be/core/src/test/java/org/apache/calcite/test/CoreQuidemTest.java#LL61C4-L66C4).

Comment: Thanks for your answer sincerely. I found it later, so If I could see your answer earlier, I wouldn 't go around the circle.